# what is this kind of object creation?

Tags: java

```
final CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(value,new Runnable(){  
public void run(){   
...statements  
}  
});
```

suppose you have a cyclic barrier in which one of the the arguments is the **direct** override of the run().
Is there a specific term for this kind of object creation?
Are there significant pros and cons in this kind of practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
new Runnable(){  
public void run(){   
...statements  
} }
```

(in Java) is called an *anonymous class*. You're creating a new class definition + instance deriving from the `Runnable` interface, and providing the `run()` method. It's anonymous, since it's not named, and you can't re-use that definition elsewhere.